# Application object restrictions in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have to modify a page that is using VBScript.

I have a problem to set local variable to Application object in a function. The code below, in the `getObjectSchema` function, generates an error:

```
Set LocalSchema = Application("ObjectSchema")
```

While the code below, in the main body (outside of any functions) works absolutely fine:

```
Set Schema = Application("ObjectSchema")
```

Does anybody knows what is wrong? Are there any limitations for access to Application objects from a function?

Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1 {
        width: 87px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
        Option Explicit

        Dim ObjectSchema
        Dim strXML
        Dim strXML1
        Dim sUserId

        On Error Resume Next

        Function GetUserID()
            GetUserID = "{3450E0D8-EE30-48EE-B63F-486506AD1D97}"
        End Function

        Function getObjectSchema()
            Dim LocalSchema

            Set LocalSchema = Application("ObjectSchema")

            If LocalSchema Is Nothing Then
                Set LocalSchema = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  
            End if

            If LocalSchema.Exists(sUserId) Then
                strXML = LocalSchema.Item(sUserId)
            Else
                strXML = "<head><title>Title</title></head><head1><title1>Title1</title1></head1>"
                LocalSchema.Add sUserId, strXML
                Set Application("ObjectSchema") = LocalSchema
            End if

            getObjectSchema = strXML
        End Function

        sUserId = GetUserID()
        strXML = ""
        strXML1 = ""
        strXML = getObjectSchema()
        strXML1 = getObjectSchema()
        strXML = getObjectSchema()
        strXML1 = getObjectSchema()

        Dim Schema

        Set Schema = Application("ObjectSchema")

        If Schema Is Nothing Then
            Set Schema = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  
        End if

        If Schema.Exists(sUserId) Then
            strXML = LocalSchema.Item(sUserId)
        Else
            strXML = "<head><title>Title</title></head><head1><title1>Title1</title1></head1>"
            Schema.Add sUserId, strXML
            Set Application("ObjectSchema") = Schema
        End if   

        strXML1 = strXML
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I have "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'Application'"

Answer (score 1):

Try a null check before setting `LocalSchema`:

```
If Not Application("ObjectSchema") Is Nothing Then
    Set LocalSchema = Application("ObjectSchema")
End If
```

**UPDATE**

You have this running in a `<script type="text/vbscript">` element, which I think means it's interpreted by the browser (specifically Internet Explorer because of the `vbscript` business).

The browser may not have a concept of an `Application` object.

Try enclosing your code in a code-block (to run it at the server) instead:

```
<body>
    <%
    Option Explicit

    Dim ObjectSchema
    Dim strXML
    Dim strXML1
    Dim sUserId

    ...

    strXML1 = strXML
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: Application object is undefined when code is in function. And it is Empty when it is in main code

Comment: Yes, I did try it. No luck.